# Is it necessary to use mysql_real_escape_string() for image into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image, mysql-real-escape-string

For example:

```
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table set image='$data'....
```

Is this a correct way to stick with?

Comment: You might lose data integrity because of encoding type, data types and some other factors.

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements. Prepared statement parameters aren't vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend keeping it unless there is a reason to remove it, as its a good way to prevent sql injection. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php .

It is probably possible to do sql injection through an image that a user could upload or a client could accidentally use.

A reason not to use it could be performance. I would tend to recommend security over performance.

Answer (score 6):

You could do a `base64_encode` to keep the integrity of your data, and assure that you will not have problems with characters of any kind, actually it is a very common way to keep and transfer data. And to get it back use `base64_decode`.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel well it is not useless. AES is slow and is for encryption. base64 does not have special chars that could ruin your day, and then it has a nice output string, and is not that slow. And the best part is that solves the security problem pretty well.

Comment: there are no security problems, dude. And one have to use **proper tool**, not one producing *nice output*, my foot

Comment: Well @Col.Shrapnel , a nice output (safe output) means it will be compatible with the many ways you  might want to use it, without causing problems, and I expressed the idea of security as in if it might be an sql injection attack (highly doubtful) it would be rendered useless by this technique. And it will also get rid of all special chars that you might want to know about and treat. So, for a quick code it is the best tool you might find. Do you propose a better solution? Did I forgot to mention that it really is a very common method, and it did not failed yet?

Comment: the only indeed **common** method is to escape a string you are inserting in the database, as it is described in the accepted answer. But it seems at least 7 people here have no idea have to properly handle SQL queries and thus devising weird methods of their own.

Comment: Well @Col.Shrapnel as I can recall the question was about how to insert a **FILE** into the database, and files, and this one, especially, as it was mentioned was an **IMAGE**, so by all means I think you cannot use the damn `mysql_real_escape_string` as it, if nothing else, will surely  ruin the actual data you want to keep in your database. Forget the security and think of this... ah, and I forgot, "my foot"!

Comment: can you provide a link to that odd question? and have you ever encountered such a circumstances yourself, in your own practice, not just by reading some internet resources of vague competence? and what is particular reason for this function to "ruin" the data?